# How to trap double key press in javascript?

Tags: javascript, keypress

I would like to be able to trap the double key press (for the Char T for example) in order to do some special processing.I would like the key presses to happen fast enough to not be interpreted as two separate presses, just like the double click.
Any ideas how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When the key(s) are hit, make a note of the time. Then compare it with the time you noted the *last* time they key(s) were hit.

If the difference is within your threshold, consider it a double. Otherwise, don't. Rough example:

```
var delta = 500;
var lastKeypressTime = 0;
function KeyHandler(event)
{
   if ( String.fromCharCode(event.charCode).toUpperCase()) == 'T' )
   {
      var thisKeypressTime = new Date();
      if ( thisKeypressTime - lastKeypressTime <= delta )
      {
        doDoubleKeypress();
        // optional - if we'd rather not detect a triple-press
        // as a second double-press, reset the timestamp
        thisKeypressTime = 0;
      }
      lastKeypressTime = thisKeypressTime;
   }
}
```

Comment: This solution uses the Ctrl key.  He does not say he needs that (although it makes sense to me).

Comment: **@Josh Stodola:** HA! Shows how careful i read... Saw "Char T", read "Ctrl T"... oops!

Answer (score 13):

Have a variable (perhaps `first_press`) that you set to true when a keypress event happens, and start a timer that will reset the variable to false after a set amount of time (however fast you want them to press the keys).

In your keypress event, if that variable is true then you have a double press.

Example:

```
var first_press = false;
function key_press() {
    if(first_press) {
        // they have already clicked once, we have a double
        do_double_press();
        first_press = false;
    } else {
        // this is their first key press
        first_press = true;

        // if they don't click again in half a second, reset
        window.setTimeout(function() { first_press = false; }, 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: AND you can make "half-a-second" a configurable persistent value which users can change. Usability rules!

Comment: I wasn't trying to provide a drop-in solution for him.  Just showing him the general idea.

Comment: Regardless, you're going to have tons of timeouts going at once, which will eventually bring the users browser to its knees.  Shog's answer using Date is definitely better.

Comment: **@Josh Stodola:** that could probably be avoided by saving the timer ID somewhere and stopping it prior to starting a new one. That said, it's more work than just keeping a timestamp... The only use i can think of for it would be if you wanted to perform two different, mutually-exclusive actions for single-press and double-press: a check in the timer callback could trigger the former if `first_press` was still true, and the latter if it was false.

Answer (score 3):

I know is too late to answer but here goes how I have implemented that:

```
let pressed;
let lastPressed;
let isDoublePress;

const handleDoublePresss = key => {
    console.log(key.key, 'pressed two times');
}

const timeOut = () => setTimeout(() => isDoublePress = false, 500);

const keyPress = key => {
    pressed = key.keyCode;

    if (isDoublePress && pressed === lastPressed) {
        isDoublePress = false;
        handleDoublePresss(key);
    } else {
        isDoublePress = true;
        timeOut();
    }

    lastPressed = pressed;
}

window.onkeyup = key => keyPress(key);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In addition to the answer you've provided, please consider providing a brief explanation of why and how this fixes the issue.