# Capturing distinct keypresses

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

When you hold down a key, the JQuery events start to pop out like crazy for this single key press:

```
...
keydown
keypress
keyup
keydown
keypress
keyup
...
```

Is there any (even non-browser-portable) way to capture **only one event for each key pressed** (example: press A and hold it down, and this should yield only one function call)?

Cheers!

Comment: Yes: `bind` to only one of those events.

Answer (score 5):

I have found that keyup works the best...

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  alert(e.keyCode);
});
```

Comment: But that produces multiple events per single key press.

Comment: @Mike: binding to an event does not produce more events.

Comment: You mean $(document).bind('keydown', callback)? It does.

Comment: No it does not.  This event will fire every time you lift a finger off a key.

Comment: And karim79, what are you doing?  jQuery takes care of the keyCode browser problem.  Edit with care, please.

Comment: Probably an inconsistent behavior across different browsers. In mine(Fx 3.5.2 Gecko/20090804) binding an event to a function that calls console.log gives me the auto-repeating(tested with both keydown and keyup).

Comment: Well OK...  I've been using keyup for 10 years and I promise you it does not fire more than once per key stroke.  I don't care what console.log tells you!

Comment: Not sure how you are "binding" but you need to do it like how I've done it in the answer.

Comment: Actually, I've tried that before asking the question. Which browser/OS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're giving jQuery a callback, you're surrendering to it's wits.  However, you could introduce some more latency for excessive notifications by installing some sort of lazy event queue that you process every tenth of a second.

```
queue = new Array();
setTimeInterval( 100, function() { queue.process(); } );

queue.process = function( ) { 
    key = queue[0];
    process( key );

    // consume equivalent keypresses by shifting array
    var originallength = queue.length;

    // find shift size
    var firstdiff = 1;
    for(; firstdiff < queue.length && queue[ firstdiff ] == key; 
          firstdiff=firstdiff+1 ) 
    {}
    var newlength = originallength - firstdiff;

    // shift everything and delete trailing tail
    var i = firstdiff;        
    for( var j = 0; j != newlength; j=j+1 ) { queue[ j ] = queue[ j+firstdiff ]; }
    for( var k = newlength; k != originallength; k=k+1 ) { queue[k]=null; }
}

$(document).keyup( function(e) { queue[ queue.length ] = e; } );
```

Or prevent appending to the queue alltogether using a minimal time diff between keypress events, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223764/how-to-trap-double-key-press-in-javascript/1223775#1223775).