# Trying to make a keyup used for 2 functions based on a timer

Tags: javascript

There is a button linked to a machine that sends a keypress to this app

Sometimes the button will "double tap" the key combination (Double shift + S)

Tried some of the responses over here: "[How to trap double key press in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223764/how-to-trap-double-key-press-in-javascript)"
as it seems along the lines of what I need but can't seem to get any to work

```js
function myFunction(xml) {
        // Start on keypress
        document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 83 && e.shiftKey)
                // Set a baseline for first keypress to compare later
                var lastKeypressTime = 0;

            // Code to run after initial keypress here
            // Basically a bunch of TTS reading from XML until either it finishes, or a button is pressed for a reload


            // I think this is kind of along the lines of what I'm after but can't quite implement it properly
            // Detect the keypress
            document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 83 && e.shiftKey)
                    // Set time of keypress to compare
                    var thisKeypressTime = new Date();
                // if time between first keypress is greater than 2 seconds, let the page reload
                if (thisKeypressTime - lastKeypressTime >= 2000)
                    window.location.reload();
                else
                // Otherwise, ignore all keypresses until the 2 seconds (at least) has passed before the button press works again
            })
        })
    }
```

Due to the button being... imperfect.. When it registers a single press as a double press, the page is reloaded instantly

Basically needing either the first keypress that "starts" the TTS to never register a faulty double press, or have any consecutive keypress ignored entirely until after a certain period has passed or something to that extent

Any guidance or alternatives to what I'm trying to accomplish would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const delta = 1500;
let lastPress = 0;

function handleKeyPress(event) {
  let currentPress = new Date();
  if (event.key === "S" && event.shiftKey) {
    if (currentPress - lastPress <= delta) {
      alert("Shift + s");
      currentPress = 0;
    }
    lastPress = currentPress;
  }
}

document.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyPress);
```

This is a snippet that works, you have to define the lastPress variable outside your function, and I don't understand why you're trying to register two listeners for the keyup event. Once that you've defined your listener handler, it will be called every time the event that you're listening on is fired; this is why you have to save the lastPress and the currentPress times.

P.S.
Obviously instead of alert something on the double keypress you can run your own function.